# Created ZIP archive is invalid

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I'm using ZipFile.Open() to create an archive, then adding entries using CreateEntryFromFile(). The resulting file is invalid according to Windows. 7-zip can open the file, but only part of the files are listed.

The code looks like this:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(archivePath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        object myValue = reader.GetValue(0);
        string objectId = myValue.ToString();
        string objectPath = Path.Combine(myPath, objectId);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(objectPath);
        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(files[0], Path.GetFileName(files[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I do dispose of the ZipArchive when I'm done, and unlike every other question about this problem, I don't use any streams, so there's nothing to flush.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what happens if you create two entries with the same filename... Maybe make sure you don't have duplicate values for `Path.GetFileName(files[0])`?

Comment: @canton7 I'm sure there are no duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that the file being added to the archive is being used by another process and cannot be accessed. To avoid this, you can try wrapping the **CreateEntryFromFile** method in a try-catch block and handle the **IOException** that could be thrown if the file is in use. You can also try closing any streams or file handles that may have been opened on the file before adding it to the archive.